# Extending BaseAdapter for ListView getView updating the view improperly

Tags: android, android-view, baseadapter

I have a RSS feed viewer and wanted to show the user the last time they listened to a particular feed.

This works for the first items loaded in the list (the items that are visible in the current view), but as the user scrolls down the listview, the `lastViewedText` for every other viewed feed is hidden. Additionally, when the user scrolls back up to the top (where the `lastViewedText` was successfully displayed before) the `lastViewedText` is now hidden. The BaseAdapters `getView` method is where I set the visibility.

Custom BaseAdapter:

```
public class PodcastAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private ArrayList<Podcast> feed;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public PodcastAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Podcast> feed){
        this.feed = feed;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return feed.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return feed.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if(convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rss_listview_item, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView desc = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.description);
        TextView date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.date);
        TextView lastViewedText = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lastViewedText);

        Podcast feedIndex = feed.get(position);

        title.setText(feedIndex.Title);
        desc.setText(feedIndex.Description);
        date.setText(feedIndex.Date);
        lastViewedText.setText(feedIndex.LastViewedText);


        if(feedIndex.LastViewedText.equals("")){
            lastViewedText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Why is the view not updating properly? The title, desc, date are all loaded properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   if(feedIndex.LastViewedText.equals("")){
            lastViewedText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            lastViewedText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

The view is hidden in the convert view, and you dont unhide it:)

Also, you can use [TextUtils.isEmpty(CharSequence string)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), to check if a String is empty or null.

Answer (score 1):

do that instead:

```
    if(feedIndex.LastViewedText.equals("")){
        lastViewedText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        lastViewedText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```